# GCloud Firewall rules on network load balancer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I just deployed a container with kubernetes to google cloud and all is working except that I couldn't figure out how I can apply default network rules to network load balancer to restrict accesses per incoming ip address.

I see that underlying instance group has the firewall rules applied but not to the service.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 4):

It appears that kubernetes server "load balancer" creation automatically creates firewall rule on a given port for 0.0.0.0/0 and it is attached to instance template and that template is used to spin off GCEs.